# Mirror bash shell on smartphone for Rails debugging

Tags: bash, ssh, mirroring

I have several shell instances active while working on a Rails app (server, vim, app root shell, etc). I would like to make use of the idle smartphone I have sitting next to my computer, that also has a good SSH client on it. Is there a way I can mirror the output of one of my local machine shells on a remote terminal so that I can quickly monitor when I hit a `debugger` line in my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/). Start screen on your computer and connect w/ your smartphone to the computer. Once you have a shell on the phone, attach to the running screen with `screen -x`. The output will then appear both on the phone and on your computer's terminal. The learning curve of screen is a bit steep, but it's a wonderful program for purposes like yours (and many others).

Comment: Thanks Gerald, this is so frikkin cool.

the commands here:

On host:

`screen -S myscreenname`

On client:

`ssh user@host`
`screen -x myscreenname`